# Size of matplotlib surface is too small

Tags: matplotlib, zooming, surface

I'm trying to save an image of a surface, but the size is too small. I wrote a simple code explaining the issue

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.figure
from matplotlib import cm

#Meshgrid + Gaussian

x = np.arange(0,10,.1)
y = np.arange(0,10,.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
u = np.exp(-(X-5)**2/2-(Y-5)**2/2)/(2*np.pi)

#Surface + size setting

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25.6,19.2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,u,linewidth=0,cmap=cm.inferno)

#Removing axes and saving

plt.axis('off')
plt.grid('off')
plt.savefig('A.png',format='png',dpi='figure')
```

I tried several methods and what worked best is `figsize`, that's why I'm using it in the sample code; anyway what happens is that it reaches a maximum zoom on a certain width/height ratio and cannot go over it no matter how much I change the values. The best I could get is the output of the code, in the following image

[image]

But it's not enough, I want it bigger such as in this edit

[image]

I tried several methods, basing on official documentantion and the answers to similar questions I found here. Here a list of commands I tried and didn't work properly, or at all

```
#plt.gca().set_aspect('auto')

#plt.imshow(surf,aspect='auto')

#plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15,10)

#ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d',aspect='auto')

#w, h = matplotlib.figure.figaspect(.5)
#fig = plt.figure(figsize=(w,h))
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How about adding `bbox_inches="tight"` to `savefig`?

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks for the suggestion. It zooms a little bit, but not as I want.

Comment: @Mr.T I tried this too, but had not the desired effect. I don't know GIMP: I actually need this in matplotlib because I'm trying to extend it later on for a video animation on it and I want this to be well clear and visibile.

Comment: I see. So, it is a one-off task but for multiple frames? First, [this is what bbox tight and ax.set_xlim produces.](https://imgur.com/A0FCJpX) How much more of the whitespace do you want to remove? Second, if we could establish bbox coordinates for this frame, they would be valid for all following frames?

Comment: @Mr.T I want to remove especially all that unuseful upper whitespace. For the second question, I don't know the answer... Making it right for one picture could be a start ahah

Comment: Using your script and adding `from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox; plt.savefig('A.png',format='png',dpi='figure', bbox_inches=Bbox.from_bounds(7, 3.5, 12, 9.5))`, I get [this output](https://imgur.com/IuUVoBW). The bbox values may differ, depending on figure size, dpi, backend, etc. However, if this is not a repetitive task, I would rather iteratively figure out good bbox values than trying to determine the optimal bounding box with a script.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you, it works fine! It doesn't work for the animation though. Anyway at least I can finally produce the so needed images for my presentation. Consider making it an answer

Comment: Nah, there must be better ways than this. But you are always free to write and accept your own answer.